# Cannot export csv with to_csv after reducing memory usage

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, data-science

I've opened the csv file (600mb) by

```
df=pd.read_csv(file)
```

It is quite big so I've reduced memory usage from :

[image: before]

It works in Jupter Notebook and shows:

[image: after]

I've changed types :

```
float64 ---> float32,
object ----> category,
int ------> uint16, uint8,
```

like this(e.g for object):

```
converted_obj = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df_obj.columns:
num_unique_values = len(df_obj[col].unique())
num_total_values = len(df_obj[col])

if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
    converted_obj.loc[:,col] = df_obj[col].astype('category')
else:
    converted_obj.loc[:,col] = df_obj[col]


optimized_df[converted_obj.columns] = converted_obj
optimized_df.info()
```

Now, I want to export reduced DataFrame to csv, but after I am doing it, the file sized increased to over 800mb(before - 600mb). When I am reading the new file to Jupyter Notebook the dtypes are the same as before reduction and the same thing with memory usage (1,6 GB+). What am I doing wrong ? How to extract the reduced csv ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use pictures for text and numbers.

Comment: Have you tried exporting to `csv.gz` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you save your data to csv, it is stored as text so whatever data types you set in pandas won't matter.

What you can do to reduce memory usage is to set dtype parameter in read_csv function.

Define a dictionary that maps all column names to dtype:

```
dtype_dict ={'airtime':np.float32, 'Cancelled':np.uint8 ....
```

Then use that dictionary in read_csv:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file,dtype=dtype_dict)
```